# Java Jsoup - Element isn't removed from Elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I will start from beginning, there's html with pattern like this:

```
<div id="post_message_(some numeric id)">
    <div style="some style things">
        <div class="smallfont" style="some style">useless text</div>
        <table cellpading="6" cellspaceing=.......> a lot of text inside i dont need</table>
    </div>
    Text i need
</div>
```

those div's with styles and that table is optional, sometimes there's just

```
<div id="post">
     Text i need
</div>
```

And i want to parse that text to String. Here;s the code I'm using

```
Elements divsInside = element.getElementById("post_message_" + id).getElementsByTag("div");
    for(Element div : divsInside) {
        if(div != null && div.attr("style").equals("margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ")) {
            System.out.println(div.html());
            div.remove();
            System.out.println("div removed");
        }
    }
```

I added those print lines to check if it finds them and yes, it does find correct ones, but later when I'm parsing it to String:

```
String message = Jsoup.parse(divsInside.html().replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>", "br2n")).text()
            .replaceAll("br2n", "\n");
```

String contains all that removed stuff again for some reasons.

I tried removing them by iterators, or making full for and removing elements by indexes, buut the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get `Text i need`. Use `Element`'s `ownText()` method which `Gets the text owned by this element only; does not get the combined text of all children`.

```
 private static void test(String htmlFile) {
    File input = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Element specificIdDiv = null;

    try {
        input = new File(htmlFile);
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "ASCII", "");
        doc.outputSettings().charset("ASCII");
        doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.base);

        /** Get Element id = post_message_1 **/
        specificIdDiv = doc.getElementById("post_message_1");

        if (specificIdDiv != null ) {
            System.out.println("content: " + specificIdDiv.ownText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw is it possible extract line breaks/<br /> like this?

Comment: Extract <br/>, you mean remove <br/>?